# R - Get html-addresses from data frame to rvest

Tags: r

I am new to R, and I have come upon a problem I can't solve. I would like to scrape Swedish election data at electoral district level. They are structured as can be found here http://www.val.se/val/val2014/slutresultat/K/valdistrikt/25/82/0134/personroster.html

I get the data I want by using this code:

```
library(rvest)
district.data <- read_html("http://www.val.se/val/val2014/slutresultat/K/kommun/25/82/0134/personroster.html")
prost <- district.data %>%
html_nodes("table") %>%
.[[2]] %>%
html_table()
```

But that is just for one district out of 6,227 districts. The districts are identified by the html address. In the website mentioned above it is identified by "25/82/0134". I can find the identities of all districts here http://www.val.se/val/val2014/statistik/2014_riksdagsval_per_valdistrikt.skv

And I read this semi-colon separated file into R by using this code:

`valres <-` `read_csv2("http://www.val.se/val/val2014/statistik/2014_riksdagsval_per_valdistrikt.skv" )`

(as a side note, how can I change the encoding so that the Swedish letters (e.g. å, ä, ö) are imported correctly? I manage to do that with read.csv and specifying `encoding='utf-8'` but not with read_csv)

In this data frame, the columns LAN, KOM and VALDIST give the identities of the districts (note that VALDIST sometimes just have 2 characters). Hence the addresses have the following structure http://www.val.se/val/val2014/slutresultat/K/kommun/**LAN**/**KOM**/**VALDIST**/personroster.html

So, I would like to use the combination in each row to get the identity of district, scrape the information into R, add a column with the district identity (i.e. LAN, KOM and VALDIST combined into one string), and do so over all 6,227 districts and append the information from each of those districts into one single data frame. I assume I need to use some kind of loop or some of those apply functions, to iterate over the data frame, but I have not figured out how.

**UPDATE:**
After the help I received (thank you!) in the answer below, the code now is as follows. My remaining problem is that I want to add the district identity (i.e. `paste0(LAN, KOM, VALDIST)`) for each website that is scraped to a column in the final data frame. Can someone help me with this final step?

```
# Read the indentities of the districts (w Swedish letters)
districts_url <- "http://www.val.se/val/val2014/statistik/2014_riksdagsval_per_valdistrikt.skv"
valres <- read_csv2(districts_url, locale=locale("sv",encoding="ISO-8859-1", asciify=FALSE))

# Add a variabel to separate the two types of electoral districts
valres$typ <- "valdistrikt"
valres$typ [nchar(small_valres$VALDIST)  == 2] <- "onsdagsdistrikt"

# Create a vector w all the web addresses to the district data
base_url <- "http://www.val.se/val/val2014/slutresultat/K/%s/%s/%s/%s/personroster.html"
urls <- with(small_valres, sprintf(base_url, typ, LAN, KOM, VALDIST))

# Scrape the data
pb <- progress_estimated(length(urls))
map_df(urls, function(x) {

    pb$tick()$print()
    # Maybe add Sys.sleep(1)
    read_html(x) %>% 
        html_nodes("table") %>%
        .[[2]] %>%
        html_table()
}) -> df
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

All the best,
Richard

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sprintf()` to do positional substitution and then use `purrr::map_df()` to iterate over a vector of URLs and generate a data frame:

```
library(rvest)
library(readr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

districts_url <- "http://www.val.se/val/val2014/statistik/2014_riksdagsval_per_valdistrikt.skv"
valres <- read_csv2(districts_url, locale=locale("sv",encoding="UTF-8", asciify=FALSE))

base_url <- "http://www.val.se/val/val2014/slutresultat/K/valdistrikt/%s/%s/%s/personroster.html"

urls <- with(valres, sprintf(base_url, LAN, KOM, VALDIST))

pb <- progress_estimated(length(urls))
map_df(urls, function(x) {

  pb$tick()$print()

  read_html(x) %>% 
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  .[[2]] %>%
  html_table()

}) -> df
```

HOWEVER, you should add a randomized delay to avoid being blocked as a bot and should look at wrapping `read_html()` with `purrr::safely()` since not all those `LAN/KOM/VALDIST` combinations are valid URLs (at least in my testing).

That code also provides a progress bar since it's going to take a while (prbly an hour on a moderately decent connection).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just a few follow-up questions: 1) how do I add a randomized delay? and 2) I notice that even with encoding "UTF-8" the characters are not imported correctly, can I specify an ISO-code in the encoding? Sorry about all the questions, R is very new to me.

Comment: I assume that the error message I get, "Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404.", is because of this lack of delay.  Sorry, one additional question - How can I add the identity of the district (i.e. LAN, KOM and VALDIST combined to one string variable) as an additional column in the data frame that is created?

Comment: Sorry again, the error message seems to be due to the fact that some html-addresses are not valid, as you mentioned. Where VALDIST is only two characters the address is different. I managed to solve that by adding `valres$typ <- "valdistrikt"`
`valres$typ [nchar(small_valres$VALDIST)  == 2] <- "onsdagsdistrikt"`. `base_url <- "http://www.val.se/val/val2014/slutresultat/K/%s/%s/%s/%s/personroster.html"` `urls <- with(valres, sprintf(base_url, typ, LAN, KOM, VALDIST))`. But I still don't know how to add a column with district id, i.e. LAN, KOM and VALDIST.

Comment: It'd prbly be easier if you updated the question with the updates you've done (it's hard to follow along w/code in the comments). the 404's are what I alluded to w/the "safely" sentence.

Comment: Thank you for the help and the suggestion, I have updated the question. My remaining problem is to add the district identity to the data frame. I assume I should do this within the map_df by substringing from the webaddress or by sending more arguments in, but I can't figure out how. Can you help?